# Symfony2 how to render all rows of form in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I built a form in symfony with this code:

```
foreach ( $options as $field => $title ) {
    $form->add( $field, 'text', array('label' => $title, 'mapped' => false ) );
}
```

And I can't find a way to render all the rows of this form in twig.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. I've found how to do this.
In Twig:

`{% for child in form.children|keys %}
    {{ form_row(attribute(form.children,child)) }}
 {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this : ?

```
{{ form(form) }}
or
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: No, I need to render each row separately. Something like this: {{ form_row(form.sport) }} but I don't know the name of fields